# NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException when running as Web Application under Eclipse

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm running a Googe App Engine Web Application under Eclipse and I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException when I try to run the servlet. I've checked my build path and added httpclient-4.2.3.jar to my classpath but I still get the error. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /cron/PromobotServlet. Reason:

    org/apache/http/HttpRequest
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest

...

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest
```

Comment: Maybe add the full error trace ? What class is missing ?

Comment: Further down I get this:

 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:199)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 at promobot.PromobotServlet.<init>(PromobotServlet.java:58)


However I've checked and the Servlet class file is in WEB-INF\classes\promobot

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add httpcore-4.2.3.jar as well, I guess you are not using Maven ?

Try adding [this](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.3/httpcore-4.2.3.jar) into your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not using Maven, no. I added that JAR and then got this:
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /cron/PromobotServlet. Reason:
    org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder

I ended up adding a whole bunch of libraries from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/ just to fix that error. I don't know why, but when I imported sendgrid-java-2.2.2.jar into my project I needed a whole bunch more libraries than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add supported classes to remove above exception. You can download here [HTTP Core](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpcore423jar.htm)

Download above jar file and add in your project libraries. May be you will get any other exception like `logger` the you need to add the jar file for the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I needed a whole bunch more jar files that I found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/